# Regular expression for tags in PHP using compound words

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Here is my code so far:

```
if (preg_match('/\s/',$tagName)){
    $_ErrorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorBox'>";
    $_ErrorMessage.= "<b>Error!</b> La etiqueta no puede contener espacios. Asegúrese de escribirla correctamente.";
    $_ErrorMessage.= "</div>";
} elseif(preg_match('/[^A-Z]/i', $tagName)){
    $_ErrorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorBox'>";
    $_ErrorMessage.= "<b>Error!</b> La etiqueta no puede contener carácteres especiales. Cáracteres especiales son todos aquellos que no estan dentro del alfabeto. Por favor escríbala de nuevo.";
    $_ErrorMessage.= "</div>";
} else {
    $insertNewTagQuery = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE INTO solution_tags (SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME)VALUES(LOWER('%s'))", $tagName);
    if($DBConnect->query($insertNewTagQuery)){
        header("Location:http://127.0.0.1/helpdesk/admin/thankyou.php");
    }
}
```

With the code above, I'm checking whether the string where the tag is, has blank spaces and whether it has any special characters other than the ones in the alphabet.

Giving it a second thought, and after the engineer in the class said that tags can be compound words and have special characters and numbers such as `Internet Explorer` or 'google-chrome' or `HTML5` I decided to modify this tiny script.

The problem is that I have no experience whatsoever on building regular expressions.

How can I do a regular expression with the following criteria?

- Compound words
- Dash special character in the middle of two words (internet-explorer, google-chrome)
- No white spaces at the beginning or end of the string

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Who said I was parsing HTML? It's a string I need to verify so that it meets the criteria mentioned above to make a tag valid. There is no HTML involved.

Comment: You have HTML tags in your strings.  If you are trying to figure out what is tags and what is not tags, then you are parsing HTML.  You may find ways to do it that work for right now, but down the road you will be frustrated.

Comment: @AndyLester, why are you assuming `$tagName` is HTML?  `$_ErrorMessage` is HTML, but that's not being tested.

Comment: @Yisera, instead of rejecting strings that start or end with space, you could just remove leading and trailing spaces.  Wouldn't that be easier on your users?

Comment: True. Forgot to bout that. I did sanitize the string, but I forgot I can remove white spaces at the beginning and ending of a string with just pure PHP functions. As for the rest, Supporting Jeremy's comment, `$tagName` is indeed a string captured from a textbox where the user will input a string containing a tag for a blog (Read the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PHP regular expression that meets your requirements:

```
/^\b[-a-z \d]*\b$/i
```

Comment: Awesome. THanks a lot! I promise I will look at a tutorial for regular expressions. I just don't have enough time to look for it right now since the project is due for this friday.